# Apex: 22.1.1 - Based on the selection of the radio groups the form must be displayed dynamically

Tags: oracle-apex

I am a newbie to APEX. I am currently working on radio buttons.. There are radio button groups in my page 1. For example :Radio 1 and Radio 2.Based on the selection of the radio button in these 2 groups , I need to dynamically show a Page items of the region in the same page. For a particular selection of the radio button groups, certain page items will be visible and certain will be hidden.

Also based on the values entered in the page items, on submit,the next page must display all the values which I entered in the region of the page elements.

What should be my approach to this. Please guide.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJgC8.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you described it, you'd use **dynamic actions** (Show / Hide) because they let you "dynamically" (and immediately) manipulate other items on the page.

You *could* use Server-side conditions as well, but they require page to be submitted first so - I guess that's not what you're after.

Therefore: initially hide all items you don't need (that's the same dynamic action, just set it to *fire on initialization*, i.e. when page is first rendered), and then show them as radio buttons' values change.

---

As of your next question: if you navigate to the next page using a button (so its action is to "Redirect to page in this application"), you can set next page's items' to values of items on this page. To do that, use **Target - Link builder** property (right below "Action").

Comment: Can you please help me to get better clarity on this.. If i select 'A' in radio1  group and option 'C in radio2 group , page item textbox1 and textbox2 must be displayed and if i am selecting option 'C' in radio1 and option 'D' in radio 2 then pageitem textbox3 and textbox4 must be displayed.